# Is accessing a device driver in Linux only possible using its device file?

Tags: c, linux, device-driver

Let's say I have a webcam, and I installed the device driver for this webcam in my Linux OS, now a device file will be created for the device driver (for example: `/dev/video0`).

Now say I want to create a program in `C` that wants to access this webcam. How can my program access the device driver for the webcam, should my program use the device file (`/dev/video0`) to access the device driver, or is there another way?

Comment: Depends on the device class.

Comment: For most practical purposes, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Most webcam drivers are compatible with [Video4Linux APIs](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/open.html), which uses same old nodes in `/dev` as many other device drivers (`tty`s, disks, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You asked a general question, and then gave a specific example. I'll try to address both.

When you load a driver, the way to communicate with it from user space is by whatever means this driver defined. Typically, this is through a `/dev` device created for the driver. If that's the case, yes, that's the only way to communicate with it.

This is not universally true. Many drivers also have entries under the `/sys` sysfs pseudo file system, and some aspects can be modified through there. In fact, there are whole classes of drivers that are *only* accessible through the `/sys` fs. Prominent examples are GPIO and Led devices, that can be turned on and off via access to `/sys/class/gpio` and similar paths.

Another option, considered deprecated but still sometimes used, is to use the `/proc` pseudo file system. Again, this is up to the driver to define its communication method. As the user, you will have to follow whatever protocol the driver defined.

Also, some drivers don't have any file system presence at all. The most obvious standard example are network interfaces. The only way to communicate with them is via the networking system calls.

In the particular example you provided, you talked about a video camera that appears as `/dev/video0`. Such a camera is, usually, a Video4Linux (or v4l) camera, and those are accessed via their character devices.

With that said, the protocol for communicating with the camera might have wrappers that makes life easier. If you open the actual device, you might have to implement a rather complicated handshake with it. Instead, you can use the v4l library to wrap the details of the access.

Make no mistake. You're still talking to the character device in `/dev`. It's just that it's not your code that does it, but the library's.